# How to recreate Task Recurrence on VF page

Tags: visualforce, tasks, task-recurrence

Has anyone replicated the task recurrence functionality on a VF page? It looks like it uses javascript in an `Activity.js` file to do the showing/hiding of applicable fields based on the user selecting the frequency (Daily/Weekly/etc.) My VF override page doesn't seem to include this `Activity.js` file.

I was curious if anyone had a snippet of code that replicated this or perhaps knew of a VF component. I'm hesitant to try hack it too much to include `Activity.js`, rely on that, and just hope Salesforce never changes it.

My other alternative is to just replicate it all manually! :)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm, what your looking for is 
`.isRecurrence`, I've never done it.. So I don't have any code for a proper answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this link, I hope this works

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000099MtIAI

Comment: Can you expand this answer and post some relevant content from the link? Links go stale over time!